# how to add extract/extract all option on right click of .rar file in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-universal, winrar, windows-10-desktop

I have windows 10, and install winrar on it. but if I try to extract the .rar files by right click on that, on right click menu I haven't find extract or extract all option.If I double click on .rar file it opens the content in winrar explorer.but could not able to extract that content. also zip, extract option is missing.
how to add that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open winrar.

Switch to “Options” tab and then, open “Settings” option.

Once again switch to “Integration” tab in the new window.

Check the option named “Integrate WinRAR into shell” and click ok.

Comment: I have checked this ,it is same settings as you said, I again clicked OK and restrat PC but not worked.

Comment: __Run__ WinRAR __as administrator__ and then follow the instructions given by [Hien Nguyen](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5944656/hien-nguyen).